# Do Wizz Go or Wizz Flex allow you to change seats multiple times for free?

Tags: wizz-air

I have purchased Wizz Go tickets and additional Wizz Flex for them. According to Wizz Air site:

> WIZZ Go: free seat selection (excluding front row and extra legroom seats)

I've checked my booking on the web app, and I can change my seats for free, but can I do it multiple times before check-in for free?

I've checked [General conditions of carriage of passengers and baggage](https://wizzair.com/static/docs/default-source/downloadable-documents/wauk-gcc---1st-of-july-2020_final_30edd4ae.pdf) and googled the question, but didn't find any information related to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked it myself. It seems like with Wizz Go + Flex you can change your seats for free as many times as you want. I've changed my seats two times after initial booking before check-in, and I had the possibility to change seats after check-in for free as well.

Keep in mind, that Wizz Go allows you to choose seats for free except first row and extra legroom seats.